# form action to email HTML form and redirect user to new URL in IIS 7.5? sendmail equivalent for .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, email, iis

I have a large HTML form which has approximately 60 fields with a lot of jQuery based conditional fields, validation, and a lot of CSS applies to UL and LI tags.

The goal is to email the form responses and redirect user to a specific URL upon form submit.

SMTP has been configured on IIS 7.5 and is working.  What I don't have is a .Net based sendmail equivalent on IIS that does not require for me to code in every single form field.

I have seen numerous solutions out there which suggest to wrap the form fields into `<asp:textbox>` `<asp:checkbox>` etc. tags, but that is totally out of the question.  I need to preserve the existing form as is in HTML markup of the page and simply find a suitable form action that will allow me to post the form such that it's emailed out (and hopefully redirected to a new URL).

I understand that I may need to create an emailer script and I realize that it there is `System.Net.Mail` I am just not clear how to pass my entire form into the [mail.Body](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.1.aspx) without that it has to become an ASP form first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request.Form` to access posted form from any `HttpHandler`, `Page` or `Controller`. Given that you only need to post, maybe `HttpHandler` is the best choice actually.

Then it is up to you how to work keys/values in `Request.Form` to build your email.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I was really hoping for a FormMail script that doesn't require me to type out all the fields I want to add to the email.  I think it's mindboggling that there is no viable solution for IIS.  How are designers supposed to create forms if they need to know asp.net to make something simple as emailing the form work.

Comment: The thing is — even if there is a solution, stackoverflow answers will always focus on things useful to developers, not designers. That is just the way this site works. Note that you do not have to type out all fields, it is pretty easy to use `foreach` to iterate through the keys.